# Why is form: FormGroup showing 'controls' as undefined in an Angular11 component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

I'm new to Angular 11 and TypeScript in general.. I'm attempting to access the 'controls' property in an explicitly defined 'FormGroup' var. It keeps telling me that property is undefined...

```
send(form: FormGroup): void{
    let jsonModel = {
      materialNum: form.controls['materialNum'].value,
    };

    let jsonModelRaw: string = JSON.stringify(jsonModel);
    //...
}
```

[image]

I have the following declared:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, NgForm, Validators, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
```

Component's HTML:

```
  <mat-vertical-stepper [linear]="isLinear" #stepper>
    <mat-step [completed]="stepOneDone" [stepControl]="newMaterialFormGroup">
      <form [formGroup]="newMaterialFormGroup"
            name="newMaterialForm"
            #newMaterialForm="ngForm"
            (ngSubmit)="send(newMaterialFormGroup.value)">
        <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out new material form</ng-template>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Material #</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Material ID" formControlName="MaterialNum" required>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML template for which your TS code relates—it could be a binding issue.

Comment: @miqh Just added the important piece, I'm using stepper and i think i figured out why its not working. I'm sending *value* not the actual formGroup object!

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @miqh for making me realize the mistake. In the HTML I was passing the FormGroup's value as the argument instead of the object itself. So, I was technically passing in raw JSON.

So this piece `(ngSubmit)="send(newMaterialFormGroup.value)">` should be changed to
 `(ngSubmit)="send(newMaterialFormGroup)">`

Doing so passes the object and thus allowing me to access `controls` successfully.

But the question remains... Why didn't TS detect this if I stated explicitly that the parameter was of type `FormGroup` and I have strong typing enabled.