# Why did TypeScript 4 transpiler not see this incorrect type passed to function?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

I had a different question which now lead me to this one here.

My original question was this:
[Why is form: FormGroup showing 'controls' as undefined in an Angular11 component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579147/why-is-form-formgroup-showing-controls-as-undefined-in-an-angular11-component)

> So this piece (ngSubmit)="send(newMaterialFormGroup.value)"> should be
> changed to  (ngSubmit)="send(newMaterialFormGroup)">
>
> Doing so passes the object and thus allowing me to access controls
> successfully.
>
> But the question remains...

Here is the component side:

```
send(form: FormGroup): void{
    let jsonModel = {
      materialNum: form.controls['materialNum'].value,
    };

    let jsonModelRaw: string = JSON.stringify(jsonModel);
    //...
}
```

I'm using `"typescript": "~4.1.5"`

Why didn't TS detect this if I stated explicitly that the parameter was of type `FormGroup` and I have strict typing enabled in TypeScript settings.

Comment: What is the type of `newMaterialFormGroup`? And what is the type of `newMaterialFormGroup.value`? My guess would be that the latter has a type of `any`.

Comment: @VLAZ Well the type of `newMaterialFormGroup` is `FormGroup`, and i have thaat explicitly set in the function parameters. This is why I'm curious; i was originally passing the value of `newMaterialFormGroup` but TS didn't reaalize it and no error was thrown about casting `value` to `FormGroup`. I just checked and `value` is of type `any` so that actually makes sense then... Still wrapping my head around all this lol.

Comment: Well, `any` is assignable to anything so...there is that. It's basically an escape clause from the type checking system. Whenever possible you should use `unknown` instead of `any`. It's similar in a way because can say `let x: unknown = 4` - anything is assignable to `unknown`. However, `unknown` is not assignable to anything `let y: number = x;` would fail compilation unless you check if the type is correct. This makes `unknown` useful as it serves as a "wildcard" type but doesn't bypass the type system.

Comment: This is great to know! please provide an answer and I will surely accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the type of `newMaterialFormGroup.value` was `any`. This is why there was no compilation error when it was passed where a `FormGroup` is expected - `any` is assignable to anything so...there is that. It is an escape clause from type checking system.

Whenever possible you should use `unknown` instead of `any`. It is similar in a way because it acts as a wildcard type anything is assignable to `unknown`. However, unknown is not assignable to anything:

```js
let a: any = 4;    // OK
let b: number = a; // OK

let x: unknown = 4; // OK
let y: number = x;  // Error
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAhgXNB2BPCBeCAWA3BHED0eEA8gNICwAUKJAEZzwCuAtjSAE6rTYHHkWXUIADzgN4Aa3gB7AO7xOWfIVIDwERPWasOaIdiUQAomzZS2QA)

You have to explicitly check an `unknown` value before you are allowed to assign it:

```
let x: unknown = 4; // OK

let y: number = -1;
if (typeof x === "number")
    y = x; // OK
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHgXBCuA7A1og9gd0RAvBALANwQD0JEA8gNICwAUPaJAJ5yLwC2ARiAE64QAtAEZC9AJYAzCAAowzAA4g00qLhx4ARO259NASnoRjEZgKjEylWnSA)

This makes `unknown` useful as it still serves as a "wildcard" type but does not bypass the type system.

For more see: ['unknown' vs. 'any'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51439843/unknown-vs-any)